# Why does Deckard first ask Joe if he has a piece of cheese?

Tags: blade-runner-series, blade-runner-2049

In *Blade Runner 2049*, when Deckard first meets Joe/KD6.3-7 the very first thing he says to him is "Mightn't happen to have a piece of cheese about you, now, would you boy"?

Any specific reason why he would ask this - assuming he'd put a lot of thought into it?

The inflection in his voice drop down on "would you boy" suggesting it's a rhetorical question.

Is it perhaps because he suspects Joe is a replicant, and the question is in some ways a conscious or even semi-sub conscious ploy i.e. a hangover of his days as a Blade Runner?  Especially the use of "boy" to provoke an emotional response.

Further, he seems somewhat satisfied or surprised at Joe's response "He reads(!)".

Comment: one minor point is in a future without milk cows, cheese would be a rare commodity indeed.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**It's a reference to *Treasure Island*.**

I didn't know the answer either, so I googled "Mightn't happen to have a piece of cheese about you, now, would you boy" and got a ton of results.

One of the results is [this copy](https://www.online-literature.com/stevenson/treasureisland/15/) of a book called [*Treasure Island*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treasure_Island) (Robert Louis Stevenson, 1883). Apparently it's a direct quote from the book:

> "Marooned three years agone," he continued, "and lived on goats since then, and berries, and oysters. Wherever a man is, says I, a man can do for himself. But, mate, my heart is sore for Christian diet. You mightn't happen to have a piece of cheese about you, now? No? Well, many's the long night I've dreamed of cheese--toasted, mostly--and woke up again, and here I were."

Another result (in fact, the first result) is [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/bladerunner/comments/76zbcs/you_mightnt_happen_to_have_a_piece_of_cheese/) where user [Alto_DeRaqwar](https://www.reddit.com/user/Alto_DeRaqwar) explains **why** Deckard quoted the book:

> Ben Gunn was a pirate; abandoned on Treasure Island by Captain Flint when he first buried his treasure. During his long sojourn on the island he develops a craving for cheese and when found by Jim (the main character of TI) it's one of the first things he asks for.
>
> So part of it is a joke on Deckard's part; he's been long stranded in Las Vegas and one of the first thing's he asks for is cheese; indicating he's the long suffering Ben Gunn abandoned by his crew mates. However a second subtler inference is around the fact that Benn Gunn also knew the true hiding place of Cpt Flint's treasure; he had found it himself and hidden it elsewhere and he would have told Jim but Jim never asked. In this case the treasure was the child and K thought himself to be the treasure; whereas if he had asked directly Deckard would have revealed the truth that it was a daughter not a son.

[Here](https://www.reddit.com/r/bladerunner/comments/7cezsm/treasure_island_quote_used_by_deckard_and_its/) is another Reddit thread. This answer comes from user [lowbrowhijinks](https://www.reddit.com/user/lowbrowhijinks):

> The line is said by Ben Gunn, a sad man who had been marooned alone on an island some 3 years. Having had no contact with any other person
> in that time, upon being discovered he timidly asked about the cheese.
> He had craved it after subsisting on goats, berries, and oysters.
>
> He had been abandoned by his peers to search for a treasure he never
> found.
>
> There are certainly parallels between Deckard and Ben Gunn. Both were
> exiled/marooned by those they associated with. Both were meeting
> someone after years in exile.
>
> Interesting as well is that the protagonist Jim says "I could now see
> that he was a white man like myself" and in the ensuing conversation
> Ben describes himself as being pious to ingratiate himself with Jim.
> He is essentially saying "This wild hermit you see before you used to
> be just like you." Both knew the same people and had the same enemy
> (Long John Silver.)
>
> There's certainly a subtext to be gleaned here- Deckard, like Ben,
> could be said to be communicating the idea "I'm not so unlike you."
>
> Deckard even says "I used to have your job once. I was good at it."
>
> The movie doesn't ever come out and just say it (like Ridley Scott
> did) but this seems to be a very subtle clue that Deckard is a
> replicant. He is the older, wilder, raggedy exile version of K.

Also apparently there's a deleted scene from the original *Blade Runner* where Holden says he's reading *Treasure Island*. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QpLoDADYF5g) is a clip.

There are a ton of other discussions on this topic. I recommend checking out the Google search if you're interested.

Comment: Cheers.  I knew it was a reference to Treasure island but I'm not familiar with the story.

Comment: "a book called Treasure Island"  - my word! That's like saying "yeah, its a quote from some movie called Star Wars"